# How to select a column location from each row if a condition match

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({Company : ['abc','def','ghi']} {"2010" : [0,100,230]} {"2011" : [120,0,300]} {"2012" : [130,240,0]})
```

## Select the first cell from the columns where year bookings is greater than 0

```
for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
    first_column = df[column_name > 0].index[0]
    first_column_value = df.iloc[first_column]
```

## Select the third column from the first_column

```
 second_column_value = df.iloc[first_GPS_index+2]
```

## Calculate CAGR

```
df['CAGR'] = (first_column.div(second_column).pow(1./2)- 1)).sub(1))*100
```

Please help me,I am getting error. I am new to python 
Result Company  First_Column_Value Second_Column_Value
       abc      100                230
       def      120                300

Comment: Can you fix the code for the dataframe constructor? That's not a valid dictionary.

Comment: Hi ayhan, I am sorry I didn't get your question. I am sorry I am very new to python or you can say programming

Comment: @PrankitRa you need to fix the syntax in your code. As it is right now, it won't run

Comment: The line starting with `df = pd.DataFrame({Company` raises a syntax error. I'd fix it myself but I don't know how that dataframe is related to what you want. You also have another dataframe apparently, called Product_GPS_1, we need to see that dataframe too. And from an initial dataframe you should show what is your expectation at the end (again, in a dataframe form maybe).

Comment: I have changed it. Sorry I have changed the naming convention because I cant show the real data. When I was copy pasting I copied the real name. It will be great if you guys help me out to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: The syntax is still invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code under some assumption about the data provided as a dict and the company as a list. Feel free to swap years and company names. If doing so, you do not need to use the transpose of the DataFrame.

See comments in code for further explanations:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
company_names = ['Company A','Company B','Company C']
data = {"2010" : [0,100,230], "2011" : [120,0,300], "2012" : [130,240,0]}

# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=col_names)

# since the data is not provided in the correct way (rows and columns are swapped)
# we need to get the transpose of the DataFrame before further processing
df = df.T

# sort index in order to make sure that years are sorted chronologically
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

# iterate through all columns and get the first index element where condition applies
# and store in dict
out = {}
for col in df:
    out[col] = df[df[col] > 0].index.tolist()[0]
print(out)
```

Giving as output:

```
      Company A  Company B  Company C
2010          0        100        230
2011        120          0        300
2012        130        240          0
{'Company B': '2010', 'Company A': '2011', 'Company C': '2010'}
```

So for example Company B had its first bookings in 2010.

In order to calculate the [CAGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_annual_growth_rate) kind of dynamically you need to know the time interval which you can assume to be one your and make sure to have data for every year. The other way would be to use a timestamp index and calculate the interval using timedeltas.

For the sake of simplicity I assume you can make sure to have complete data for every year and hard-code a time interval of one year:

```
# assume to have a time interval of one year
delta_t = 1

# in order to divide to rows we apply `df.div()` which basically divides two DataFrames.
# To divide each row with the following row we apply `df.shift(1)` to the same DataFrame
# in order to shift the DataFrame by one row (see docs on used commands for futher details).
cagr = ((df.div(df.shift(1)))**(1/delta_t) -1)*100
print(cagr)
```

Giving:

```
      Company A   Company B   Company C
2010        NaN         NaN         NaN
2011        inf -100.000000   30.434783
2012   8.333333         inf -100.000000
```

Filtering this data in order to get applicable results is up to you from this point on since having CAGRs of `NaN` (or even `inf`) does not make much sense from an economical point of view.

Comment: Thank You Albert! Its a great help!

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, please accept my answer in order to mark you question as solved.

Comment: Hi Albert, I am very new to Stack Overflow.Can you help me out how to accept your answer?

Comment: Just click on the tick next to my answer at the upper left corner.

Comment: Thank You! Albert once again